# Create a Segment of users who only visited one part of my website in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

The website in question has different parts and functionality. E.g. one part is a blog, another a shop and then there are meta-pages.
The site is structured as follows:

```
example.com/blog                 // Blog main page
example.com/blog/post-name       // Blog posts
example.com/shop                 // Shop main page
example.com/shop/product-name    // Products
example.com/legal                // Meta page
example.com/about                // Meta page
```

I want to create a segment in Google Analytics of sessions which did not leave the blog. Or in other words: once the user loads a page which does not start with `/blog`, the session is excluded from the segment.

Therefor I created the following condition for my *Blog only* segment under *Admin > Segments > Blog only > Conditions.

[image: Segment condition]

I read this as "Exclude all sessions from this segment which have a page that starts with anything other than `/blog`.

However, all sessions are ending up in this segment. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analytics segmentation conditions offer much more operators, than regex. If there's no specific reason behind choosing regex, you could simply go for the following condition, which matches your described requirement.

```
Filter >> Sessions >> Exclude
Page >> does not start with >> /blog
```

In case you prefer to or have to use regex, please find detailed description of regex in Analytics [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en). Also, I'd suggest to try the following expression, based on [this sample](http://www.regextester.com/15):

```
^((?!\/blog).)*$
```